# Is this identity for Taylor-like series known?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have discovered it roughly a month ago.

Let $$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^k). $$
Now, notice the following: $$ \frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k}) = \frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k-1}x) = \frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}(f(x)x^{k-1}) + \frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}(\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)x^{k-1})x) = ... = k\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}(f(x)x^{k-1}) + x\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k-1}). $$
Therefore
$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k(k\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}(f(x)x^{k-1}) + x\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k-1})). $$
Then, after elementary index shifting, one arrives at
$$ S = \frac{x}{1+g}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k-1}). $$
But this process can be done m times!
$$ S = (\frac{x}{1+g})^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k-m}) \implies (\frac{x}{1+g})^{m}S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^{k+m}). $$

Then I arranged a Taylor series with the m-dependent factors on both sides:

$$ \frac{1}{jf(j)} \space (where \space j = \frac{x}{1+g})*S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}g^k\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(f(x)x^k\frac{1}{xf(x)}) = \frac{1}{x}. $$
Therefore
$$ S = \frac{f(\frac{x}{1+g})}{1+g}. $$

Note that when f = exp one obtains the integrand of the exponential integral. I tried experimenting with it to obtain a new identity but I ultimately arrived at $0=0$.

Comment: $S,f,g$ are functions in $x$, yes?

Comment: f is a function, g is a variable and S is the sum. I assumed g to be independent of x.

Comment: I’m convinced by everything except the final part where you “arrange a Taylor series independent of $m$”

Comment: Those *are* dependent of m. Think of m and the iterating variable in the Taylor series.

Comment: Obviously I also assumed convergence.

Comment: Convergence is a good point. $g$ ideally should be such that $|g|\le1$ otherwise the restrictions on the derivatives of $f$ would have to be quite strong!

Comment: What do you do in "$\Rightarrow$" after saying "But this process can be done m times!"?

Comment: To the right-hand side of the implication is the equation which was on both sides divided by $ (\frac{x}{1+g})^{m}.$ After that I merely chose $m$ to be $-m$ instead.